# Run JUnit test with external parameter using gradle

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, junit, automated-tests

I have a Gradle project, in which ***gradle test*** (from the Java plugin https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) would run JUnit tests.

The test is using a network connection, and I need to pass to the test some hostname, parameter from command line of the test, preferably attached to gradle command line, or otherwise, editing build.gradle file.

How I could pass to my test a certain string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
    systemProperty 'test.hostname', System.getProperty('test.hostname')
}
```

Test case

```
Assert.assertEquals("foo", System.getProperty("test.hostname"));
```

Then from command line

```
gradle test -Dtest.hostname=foo
```